# Share image via social media from PWA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, html2canvas, web-share

In my Nuxt PWA I have a function that converts my HTML to Canvas using [this package](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). The generated image is in base 64. Now I want to be able to share that image via: Whatsapp, Facebook, email, Instagram etc.  I have found several packages but they all don't seem to support sharing files only URLs and Text.

This is my share function:

```
shareTicket(index) {
  html2canvas(this.$refs['ticket-' + index][0], {
    backgroundColor: '#efefef',
    useCORS: true, // if the contents of screenshots, there are images, there may be a case of cross-domain, add this parameter, the cross-domain file to solve the problem
  }).then((canvas) => {
    let url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png') // finally produced image url

    if (navigator.share) {
      navigator.share({
        title: 'Title to be shared',
        text: 'Text to be shared',
        url: this.url,
      })
    }
  })
```

When I take out the `if (navigator.share)` condition I get an error in my console that `navigator.share` is not a function.  I read somewhere that it only works on HTTPS so I uploaded to my staging server and tried but still got the same error.

Just to be clear I want to be able to share the generated image itself and not a URL.

Comment: What happens if you write this all in `if (process.client) { // insert your whole code here }`? And also, it looks like this is mainly used on mobile, did you tried it there or only on desktop?

Comment: Sorry I dunno what process.client means also this if for both mobile and desktop and I have tried it on both and it doesn't work.

Comment: This is from the Nuxt documentation, basically saying that the code should not run on the server. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context Following the documentation of MDN, I achieved to make the demo work properly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share You want the same result as on this page, right?

Comment: When I wrap my code in ```if (process.client)``` I still get the error ```navigator.share``` is not a function.  Didn't know about it not working with a server, not sure how to run my app then. Yes please I want to be able share files like described in the link you shared.

Comment: Have you set the package up as a [client only plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#client-or-server-side-only)? additional help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694228/using-npm-packages-client-side-with-nuxt)

Comment: Sorry what package? I'm confused.

Comment: @Porter I'm not using any 3rd party package for this though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tell me if this URL works for you: https://nuxt-share-social-media.netlify.app
If it does, you can find the Github repo here: https://github.com/kissu/so-share-image-bounty

The code is

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="capture" ref="element" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
      <h4 style="color: #000">Hello world!</h4>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <button @click="share">share please</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'

export default {
  methods: {
    share() {
      // iife here
      ;(async () => {
        if (!('share' in navigator)) {
          return
        }
        // `element` is the HTML element you want to share.
        // `backgroundColor` is the desired background color.
        const canvas = await html2canvas(this.$refs.element)
        canvas.toBlob(async (blob) => {
          // Even if you want to share just one file you need to
          // send them as an array of files.
          const files = [new File([blob], 'image.png', { type: blob.type })]
          const shareData = {
            text: 'Some text',
            title: 'Some title',
            files,
          }
          if (navigator.canShare(shareData)) {
            try {
              await navigator.share(shareData)
            } catch (err) {
              if (err.name !== 'AbortError') {
                console.error(err.name, err.message)
              }
            }
          } else {
            console.warn('Sharing not supported', shareData)
          }
        })
      })()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Inspired from @denvercoder9!

---

#### More info about the answer

- I've used [an IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) because I was not sure how the whole thing works, but it's works great in a `method` context!
- I've added a missing `async` because ESlint and in case you wanted to make something after
- I've used [`$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) because this is how you should select specific parts of the DOM in the Vue ecosystem
- I've striped some things to keep it simple, hosted on Netlify to have some simple HTTPS and tested it on Chrome (`v91`), working perfectly fine!
- Here is [the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#browser_compatibility) again to the MDN documentation of the Web Share API.

---

#### Compatibility

This is my experience for the browsers (tested on the MDN example and on my app, exact same results)

| where | working |
| --- | --- |
| iPad chrome | yes |
| iPad firefox | yes |
| iPad safari | yes |
| windows chrome | yes |
| windows firefox | no |
| android chrome | yes |
| android firefox | no |
| desktop linux chrome | no |
| desktop linux firefox | no |

For me, this was a mobile only feature (like for Android). But it looks like even some desktop browsers are handling this too. I have to admit that I was really surprised to even see this one work on Windows.
Here is an interesting post from Google that correlates this compatibility: https://web.dev/web-share/#browser-support

Reading MDN again, it says

> The navigator.share() method of the Web Share API invokes the native sharing mechanism of the device.

So, I guess that the "(desktop) device" mostly do not support the Share API.

TLDR: this is working totally as intended but the compatibility is really subpar so far.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your time.  I tried this in both the latest stable builds of firefox, chrome and edge on my Mac running BigSur and it still didn't work.  However when I tried it in safari it worked.  I tried on my phone as well and it worked with only chrome not firefox.  Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: So it looks like my code worked :-) Here's a [screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/145676/126955107-c9700e92-d436-4490-8fd6-b0ac78e12d94.png) where I test this on desktop Safari. The API is also supported on the desktop by Microsoft Edge (the Chromium-based variant). It will also soon land in macOS and Windows on Chrome. It also already works on Chrome OS.

Comment: @DenverCoder9 yep, it was probably just the funky support + having a proper verified SSL certificate to try this out.

Answer (score 3):

I have a variation of the code below in a `share()` function in an app of mine and it works fine if executed on the client.

```js
const share = async() => {
  if (!('share' in navigator)) {
    return;
  }
  // `element` is the HTML element you want to share.
  // `backgroundColor` is the desired background color.
  const canvas = await html2canvas(element, {
    backgroundColor,
  });
  canvas.toBlob(async (blob) => {
    // Even if you want to share just one file you need to 
    // send them as an array of files.
    const files = [new File([blob], 'image.png', { type: blob.type })];
    const shareData = {
      text: 'Some text',
      title: 'Some title',
      files,
    };
    if (navigator.canShare(shareData)) {
      try {
        await navigator.share(shareData);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.name !== 'AbortError') {
          console.error(err.name, err.message);      
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('Sharing not supported', shareData);            
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Does not work.  When I take out the condition I get TypeError: navigator.canShare is not a function.  Not sure if I require a Vue/Nuxt specific solution for this.

Comment: Are you sure you're running this on the client (that is, in the browser, not on the server)? Also, not all browsers support the Web Share Level 2 API, so you need to feature-detect this (`if ('share' in navigator && 'canShare' in navigator) { /*  */ }`). Do you have a URL to test this?

Comment: @DenverCoder9 it's a Nuxt app, not sure how i'm supposed to run it.  Initially I was using ```yarn dev``` to run my app but I even tried generating the static assets with ```yarn generate``` and then running ```yarn start``` but that didn't work either.

Comment: @user3718908 `yarn dev` is for local dev. If you do have `target: static`, you should `yarn generate` and `yarn start` indeed. You can even `yarn generate` and drop your `dist` directory here directly: https://app.netlify.com/drop